# Obtain the same result with one or more keys in objects

Tags: javascript, object

With these objects

```
let myObjectA = {"fruits": {"item1":1, "item2":1}, "vegetables": {"item3":1, "item4":1} },
    myObjectB = {"fruits": {"item5":1, "item6":1} };
```

I need to do the same for loop for obtaining the keys, but when I do the same for loop

```
for(var i in myObjectA){
    print(myObjectA[i]);
  }
  for(var j in myObjectB){
    print(myObjectB[j]);
  }
```

In the first loop I get the two items, but in the second I get `undefined`

How do I get the `fruits` result, even when it is only one key in the object? I need a dynamic for loop because I don't know in advance if I'll get a one or two keyed objects

Comment: Instead of I in myObjectB[i] use j

Answer (score 1):

It's a typo as mentioned, but for reference, you can also obtain object keys with... wait for it... [Object.keys](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys) :)

```js
let myObjectA = {
    "fruits": {
      "item1": 1,
      "item2": 1
    },
    "vegetables": {
      "item3": 1,
      "item4": 1
    }
  },
  myObjectB = {
    "fruits": {
      "item5": 1,
      "item6": 1
    }
  };

let keys = Object.keys(myObjectA);
console.log(keys);

keys.forEach(k => {
  let item = myObjectA[k];
  let subkeys = Object.keys(item);
  console.log(`subkeys of ${k}`, subkeys)
})
```

Answer (score 0):

You are passing `i` in `myObjectB[i]`

```
for(var i in myObjectA){
    print(myObjectA[i]);
  }
  for(var j in myObjectB){
    print(myObjectB[j]); // correction pass j not i
  }
```

Comment: Yes, was a mistake...